# recurring payment on a specific date

Tags: payment

I need to create a recurring payment that should process only twice. First, I need to get an advance amount and remaining amount should be payed in another date. Now, I would like to have the time reduces according to the initial payment date.

For instance,  assume user purchases today  then recurring will be set for 60 days, if user purchases tomorrow then it will charge in 59 days, then day after will be 58 days.

How to proceed with this?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: While this could be a programming question, it is imprecise enough that it could also be a finance question. What have you tried? Is this in the context of a programming language, framework, environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I was thinking of adding this info earlier but was not sure about your question. What you mean is also(?) called as Direct Debit. I have worked on a similar project. We charge the installments to their Bank Account and it entirely depends on your Payment Gateway how to implement it in your application.

You don't have to worry about storing their bank details. Payment gateway will take care of future payment processing. If you still need CC then you will have to speak to your payment gateway provider. Payment gateays differ from country to country. I have worked with mCheck & ICICI (India) and BTBuynet and Logic Group (UK). Let me know if you need more info.

To do this first you will need a `start date`.

So if startDate is 01/12/2009 and if I make a purchase today then then next payment processing date will be

```
(60 - (TodaysDate - StartDate))
```

Is this that difficult? Or I didn't understand your question?

Comment: I understand it better now.. thanks... do u know how to change the payment amount once it is set?  if the inital payment is $100, the user should pay $200 for the remaining.. FYI: I would be using Authorize.net gateway.

Comment: Yes that is posible. In our case we charged 3 months premium first and then followed by monthly installments. This explains :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you will need a Payment Gateway that supports recurring payments, such as protx.

Once you have that set up, they will provide you with an API, usually based on a web portal, which you can use to set up and take recurring payments.

In your code when you are processing payment, you simply pass the required variables through in the post to the web address protx provide you and they will handle the set up and retrieval of funds.

Paypal also support recurring payments.

Comment: With recurring payments you can store the date to do the payment on your end. You are then given a code to trigger a payment with the PreAuth (so you don't need to store credit card numbers). If you wrap this in a cron/scheduled task on your server you're away.